# The metric $d_{\infty}(x,y) =\max_{i = 1,\ldots,n} |x_i-y_i|$

Tags: metric-spaces, notation

We had the following metric as an example in class:

> $d_{\infty}(x,y) = \max_{i = 1,\ldots,n} |x_i-y_i|$

What exactly does the subscript under $\max$ mean? Does it mean that we take the value $i$ for which $|x_i-y_i|$ is the largest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of writing $\max_{i = 1,\ldots,n} |x_i-y_i|$ is 
$\max \{|x_i - y_i|  \;|\; i = 1, \dots, n\}$, that is, we consider the $n$ numbers $|x_i - y_i|$ ($1 \leq i \leq n$) and take the maximal one of these.